# Problema com .htaccess no amazon EC2

Tags: apache, htaccess, ubuntu, amazon-aws

Estou migrando um site para o Amazon EC2 (ubuntu com apache, php e mysql) e estou com problemas nas rotas dos links. O meu arquivo `.htaccess` está basicamente assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteRule ^fale-conosco/?$ faleconosco.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^galeria-de-fotos/?$ galeriadefotos.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tarifas/?$ tarifas.php [NC,L]
```

Ao acessar pelo navegador `www.dominio.com.br/fale-conosco` ou `/galeria-de-fotos` abre normalmente, mas o link de `/tarifas` não abre `(Not Found, The requested URL /tarifas was not found on this server.)`, porem se eu colocar `/tarifaS` (alguma letra maiuscula) o link funciona !!

Alguem saberia uma solução para tal problema ?

Comment: Este caso é intrigante. Você revisou pra ver se não tem nenhum caractere invisivel ali na linha do ``tarifas`` ?

Comment: como assim carácter invisível no arquivo ?

Comment: Rafael, veja http://www.gpupo.com/zero-width-space/ (ZERO WIDTH SPACE)

Comment: nada acontece ! recriei o arquivo .htaccess apenas com RewriteEngine On Options +FollowSymLinks  RewriteRule ^tarifas/?$ tarifas.php [NC,L] e não funciona ! mas quando mudo para tarifas2 ele abre !!! não sei mais oque fazer !

Comment: o que notei é que todas as regras que não funcionam, se eu trocar alguma letra para MAIUSCULO, o link abre, exemplo: /tarifas (não abre) , /tarifaS (abre) , e no htaccess ta s RewriteRule ^tarifas/?$ tarifas.php [NC,L]